# Create a project using AEM eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, adobe, aem, sightly

Following [this url](http://adobeaemclub.com/how-to-set-up-aem-projects-using-eclipse-plugin/) for project setup

However am stuck at step 3

**Step 3**:  'Enter the Project details like Name, Group Id and Artifact Id and Click ‘Next’. However, when I click on next twice, it changes the title to “Create or select server. This step defines which server to use with the new project.”.

Am not getting any options to create a new server.
[image]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot? What version of the AEM tooling are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Few options:

1. Maybe you can use these url's

   https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/dev-tools/aem-eclipse.html

   https://eclipse.adobe.com/aem/dev-tools/
2. Use a command line

   ```
   mvn archetype:generate \
   -DarchetypeRepository=https://repo.adobe.com/nexus/content/groups/public/ \
   -DarchetypeGroupId=com.adobe.granite.archetypes \
   -DarchetypeArtifactId=aem-project-archetype \
   -DarchetypeVersion=10 \
   -DgroupId=my-group-id \
   -DartifactId=myproject \
   -Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT \
   -Dpackage=com.mycompany.myproject \
   -DappsFolderName=myproject \
   -DartifactName="My Project" \
   -DcqVersion="6.0" \
   -DpackageGroup="My Company"
   ```
3. Use this [AEM Boilerplate](http://www.aemboilerplate.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and solved it. The cause is my Maven settings file is not correct.

I removed the settings.xml in C:\Users\{username}\.m2 (remember to backup) and then the Maven will be able to find the dependencies from global repository.

I hope it helps.